# The buttons won't change the text color or the image size. I think my javascript isn't linked correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

This is a section on debugging for prework to a code school. I cannot get the buttons to work at all. I don't have much experience but I think my javascript isn't linked correctly. The javascript file is logic.js and the css file is style.css and I've made sure they are in the same folder.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Boo The Dog</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Linking CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <!-- Linking jQuery -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="logic.js" ></script>

</head>
<body>

this is also at the bottom of the code

<script type="text/javascript" src="logic.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can't get what buttons to work? There's not enough information here to even know what you're trying to do or how you're trying to do it, so it's impossible to say why it doesn't work.

Comment: if you want to sure the your resources(logic.js and style.css) load correctly, right-click on the browser(in my case Chrome) and select "Inspect--> NetWork-->js". If your resources show up with 200 status then Resources are loaded correctly. This video in youtube can help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KbEx0s06VLs

Comment: You don't want your javascript and css in the same directory. With your `src` as you have it they need to be in document root.

Answer (score -1):

In your code, you have two script links. Can you provide your directory structure?